# How to create a tuple of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a problem in which I'm editing the value of one of the keys of a dictionary and then I want to store these dictionaries as entries of a tuple. But the problem is that the tuple seems to be adding dictionaries by reference.

An example code is provided here:

```
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dict_decision = {'policy': 'decision-rule',
                     'file': 'policy', 'nopts': 1, 'vect_td': 10}

    lifetime = 40;  # years
    vect_td = np.arange(1,lifetime)
    tup_dict = ()
    count = 0

    for td in vect_td:
        dict_decision.update({'vect_td':int(td)})
        #print(dict_decision)
        tup_dict = tup_dict + (dict_decision,)
        count = count + 1
```

At the end of the for-loop, the dictionary `dict_decision`, has the key `vect_td` = `39`. When I check the tup_dict, all the dictionaries stored inside have `vect_td` = `39` where infact I want them to vary from 1 to 39. It seems to have passed the dictionary `dict_decision` by reference. What should I do to rectify the situation?

Comment: Because you keeping adding **the same `dict`** as you build your tuple: `tup_dict = tup_dict + (dict_decision,)` as an aside, what your doing here would imply you probably just want a `list`.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of the copy function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when you call `dict_decision.update(...)`, you update the same dict instance in every iteration of the loop. This means that your tuple does indeed contain a lot of references to the same dict.

If you make a copy of the original dict before calling `update` on it, it will probably work better:

```
for td in vect_td:
    td_dict = dict_decision.copy()
    td_dict.update({'vect_td': int(td)})
    tup_dict = tup_dict + (td_dict,)
    count = count + 1
```

As suggested in the comment on your question, you probably also want a list instead of a tuple, so that you don't have to create new tuples for each iteration of the loop, but that is not strictly relevant to your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Frost. Both the suggestions are very helpful. I was unaware of the copy function.